# Failed to get the FileContents from outlook when performing drop

Tags: winapi, outlook

here is the description of my problem:

I'm dragging the mail from outlook and drop it on my form and all of these methods failed to get the FileContents from the IDataObject which i get when the drop event occured.:

1) I've tried c++ framework Qt ver 5.5. to obtain the data and got these results:

It's the formats avaible and the bytes recieved for each format:

```
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"RenPrivateSourceFolder\"" 206
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"RenPrivateLatestMessages\"" 420
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"RenPrivateMessages\"" 420
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"RenPrivateItem\"" 0
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileGroupDescriptor\"" 668
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileGroupDescriptorW\"" 1188
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileNameW\"" 0
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"FileContents\"" 0
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"Object Descriptor\"" 194
"text/plain" 166
"application/x-qt-windows-mime;value=\"Csv\"" 98
```

as you can see the FileContents format returns zero bytearray.

2) Ok,i thought the problem maybe with the qt's implementation of the drag'n'drop operation,so  i've implemented the win API approach of implementing the IDropTarget interface, involving registering my window to be able to catch

the drop event. When the drop event occurs, i get the IDataObject which must contain the data being dropped.

But results are the same. I Got the zero bytearray of the FileContents structure. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
STDMETHODIMP QDropTarget::Drop(LPDATAOBJECT pDataObj, DWORD grfKeyState,

                               POINTL pt, LPDWORD pdwEffect)
{
    static UINT cf = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR);
    static FORMATETC fmtetc = { cf, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, 0, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
    //getting the description of the files being dropped
    STGMEDIUM medium;
    HRESULT hr = pDataObj->GetData(&fmtetc, &medium);
    if (!FAILED(hr))
    {
        FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR* files = static_cast<FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR*>(GlobalLock(medium.hGlobal));
        int items_count=files->cItems;
        for (int i=0;i<items_count;i++){
            QString filename=QString::fromWCharArray(files->fgd[i].cFileName).toUtf8().data();//getting filenames - works as expected
        }
        static UINT cf = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS);
        static FORMATETC fileContentFormat = { cf, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT,0, TYMED_HGLOBAL|TYMED_ISTORAGE|TYMED_ISTREAM};
        STGMEDIUM medium2;
        HRESULT hr2 = pDataObj->GetData(&fileContentFormat, &medium2);
        if (!FAILED(hr2))
        {
            qDebug()<<GlobalSize(medium2.hGlobal);//zero result 
            qDebug()<<(medium2.pstg==NULL);//zero result
            qDebug()<<(medium2.pstm==NULL);//zero result
            qDebug()<<"Filecontents extracted";

      .......
```

3) I loaded the ClipSpy utility, which allow to drop files on it's form and show avaible formats and the size of the structure represented by each format. And again the filecontent size is zero.

Can you tell me is this an outlook problem? Is Outlook really able to pass the message content through the WINAPI approach of drag'n'drop via COM objects?Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678431(v=vs.85).aspx) says this in a roundabout way, but you have to initialize the `typed` and `pUnkForRelease` fields of the `STGMEDIUM` object you pass into `GetData()` so it can know how you want the data and who's going to be responsible for freeing it. You might get away with just zeroing out the entire structure, but you still need to define it somehow, as a stack-allocated variable has undefined contents by default, which will confuse `GetData()`. But if ClipSpy (a third party utility) is also failing...

Comment: Do you have reason to assume, that *FileContents* should not be empty?

Comment: Yes. There is a solution, written on C#(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C). And the author getting the content using the FileContents format. Here is a snippet : //using the Com IDataObject interface get the data using the defined FORMATETC this.comUnderlyingDataObject.GetData(ref formatetc, out medium)

Comment: setting pUnkForRelease doesn't change things

Comment: according to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 the FileContents format must contain the data.

Comment: Okay different question. Can you print the value of `tymed` after each `GetData()` call, *including* the outer one?

Comment: the tymed value equal to TYMED_ISTORAGE. it seems developers in outlook does not stick to the general approach of drag n drop on Windows, described in the article(link is above on my previous comment) I've asked on microsoft forum - (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b2e50357-a87c-4323-a851-5050b0e5b34b/not-able-to-get-filecontents-after-drop-on-form-occured?forum=outlookdev) and the answer from thier developer is :
The MSDN article is a general description of shell data transfer. I have given you the solution that is specific to how Outlook implements drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

it seems developers in outlook does not stick to the general approach of drag n drop on Windows, described in the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I've asked on [microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b2e50357-a87c-4323-a851-5050b0e5b34b/not-able-to-get-filecontents-after-drop-on-form-occured?forum=outlookdev) and the answer from thier developer is :

> The MSDN article is a general description of shell data transfer. I
>   have given you the solution that is specific to how Outlook implements
>   drag and drop.